# How to fill the area between the x-segments of two lines in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I'm pretty new to d3 and currently working on a multiple-line chart (in angular2 / typescript).
The underlying data is discrete, but the lines are curved using the `curveMonotoneX`.

```
this.x = d3Scale.scaleLinear().range([0, this.width]);
this.y = d3Scale.scaleLinear().range([this.height, 0]);
this.line = d3Shape.line()
        .curve(d3Shape.curveMonotoneX)
        .x( (d: any) => this.x(d.x) )
        .y( (d: any) => this.y(d.y) );
```

My goal is, to fill the area between two lines of the current x-segment (the segment between two discrete x-values) whenever it is hovered, like this:
[image: Area between two lines]

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to draw the curve the same as created by `curveMonotoneX` just for this specific line segment.
If I draw a line using only the data of the two x-values, the line won't be curved as expected but just linear since the curve integrates the neighboring points, too, which are missing now.

My best try so far was to store the output string of `this.line(data)` and manually find the correct substring according to the limiting x coordinates from `this.x(data)`. However, since the path string consists of multiple commands with varying numbers of 'arguments' it is quite difficult to always find the correct substring indeces.

**So the questions are:**

- What's the best way to fill the area between two lines' segments?
- How can get a segment of a line which is curved exactly the same as the original line? Does it have to be extracted manually or is there a better way?

Comment: This is what I'd do, provided that the blue line is always below the red line: 1. create the red path with an area generator, not a line generator, 2. create several rectangles from a x-segment to the next, all of them going from the top to the bottom of the drawing area, 3. setting the opacity of rectangles to zero and using a clone of the red path as clipPath, 4. creating the blue line with an area generator as well, with white fill, 5. when hovering over the ractangles, changing the opacity to 1.

Comment: That's a clever approach! Unfortunately, the lines may cross. But I found another way (which probably only works for `curveMonotoneX`): I duplicated the two points of the segment, but moved them a tiny bit into the direction of the next points (to the left/right of the segment). Thus, the line is curved correctly and the extra points are so close, they're not visible.

Comment: Could you use gradient fill and set the offset positions of colours in the gradient based mouseover or some other user input? For example: http://blockbuilder.org/tomshanley/34bc30efda77c388493e92128b560791

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using a linearGradient, with a function that finds the y coordinates given an x coordinate.  A rect with 0 opacity captures mouse events to show and update the linearGradients's stops and lines coordinates

https://bl.ocks.org/tomshanley/01a87c81b5ed86b6d55e566403c175ba

An area shape is created where the y0 and y1 functions are using the y values from the two lines.

```
let curve = d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5)

let area = d3.area()
    .x(function (d, i) { return xScale(i) })
    .y0(function (d) { return yScale(d.data1) })
    .y1(function (d) { return yScale(d.data2) })
    .curve(curve);

let line1 = d3.line()
    .x(function (d, i) { return xScale(i) })
    .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.data1) })
    .curve(curve);

let line2 = d3.line()
    .x(function (d, i) { return xScale(i) })
    .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.data2) })
    .curve(curve);
```

The area's fill is set to a linearGradient, which has 'stops' that are updated with mousemove event.  The stops' percentages are at set so that the white and grey change abruptly to give the impression of a solid fill, either side of the mouse's position.

```
let x = d3.mouse(this)[0]
let middle = x / width

offset1 = (middle - 0.1) < 0 ? 0 : (middle - 0.1)
offset2 = (middle + 0.1) > 1 ? 1 : (middle + 0.1)

stopsData = [
      { "offset": 0, "stopColour": "#FFFFFF" },
      { "offset": offset1, "stopColour": "#FFFFFF" },
      { "offset": offset1, "stopColour": "#777777" },
      { "offset": offset2, "stopColour": "#777777" },
      { "offset": offset2, "stopColour": "#FFFFFF" },
      { "offset": 1, "stopColour": "#FFFFFF" }
 ]

gradient.selectAll("stop")
      .data(stopsData)
      .attr("offset", function (d) { return d.offset })
      .attr("stop-color", function (d) { return d.stopColour })
```

Your sketch included lines each side of the area's fill, which I created using two lines, whose y1 and y2 attributes by set by traversing along each path until you get to the point where the x coordinate is same (or just greater than) the mouse's x position.

```
o1 = width * offset1
o2 = width * offset2

line1Ys = findYs(path1Node, o1, o2)
line2Ys = findYs(path2Node, o1, o2)

areaLine1.attr("x1", width*offset1)
    .attr("x2", width*offset1)
    .attr("y1", line1Ys[0])
    .attr("y2", line2Ys[0])

areaLine2.attr("x1", width*offset2)
    .attr("x2", width*offset2)
    .attr("y1", line1Ys[1])
    .attr("y2", line2Ys[1])

function findYs(p, x1, x2) {
            const accuracy = 1 //increase for quicker, but less accurate lines
            let ys = [];
            let i = x1;
            const l = p.getTotalLength()
            for (i; i < l; i+=accuracy) {
                let pos = p.getPointAtLength(i)
                if (pos.x > x1) {
                    ys.push(pos.y)
                    break
                }
            }
            for (i; i < l; i+=accuracy) {
                let pos = p.getPointAtLength(i)
                if (pos.x > x2) {
                    ys.push(pos.y)
                    break
                }
            }
            return ys;
        }
```

Comment: instead of using a lookup for the y values within the mousemove event, you could pre-calculate the values and store in an array for later on, eg https://bl.ocks.org/tomshanley/373640a6bc6f89293507550ae5629488